# multiple running examples

Tags: counters, examples

I need to be able to have several running examples, appearing over multiple sections and whose discussion is progressed as relevant throughout the paper, in an article intended for publication.

If I use, repeatedly,

```
\newtheorem{ex}[theorem]{Example}
\begin{ex}\label{runningEx1}
...
\end{ex}

...

\begin{ex}\label{runningEx1}
...
\end{ex}
```

I get a new number in the .pdf and a multiply defined label.
There does not seem to be a way  of indicating that I want the previous number.
I would be happy to type in a  "(continued)" myself.

If I use the thmtools package and the continues option,

```
\usepackage{thmtools}
\begin{ex}[continues=MyExmplelabel] 
..
\end{ex}
```

I do get the correct former number (yeah!!), but I also get appearing in the pdf file, "(continuing from p.)"
which I really don't want, as this not something that can appear in a final journal version, where the page numbers relate to articles outside of my paper.
I just want "(continued)."

If I don't use the \begin{ex}...\end{ex} construction, but simply use

```
\noindent\textbf{Example \ref{RunEgTrans}} (continued).\quad
```

then I'm left with trying to get the correct before and after spacing, the correct font, and so on (of course).

Finally, there is really no way to keep resetting counters and keep any kind of flexibility, I might as well give up as do that.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  would you consider numbering your examples "1a", `1b", etc.?  i can't work this out now, but might be able to later this afternoon.

Comment: This question was just closed due to being unclear, but it seems pretty clear (and simple to answer) to me. The answer is "Use the `continues` option from `thmtools` and add `\renewcommand\thmcontinues[1]{continued}` to your preamble".

Answer (score 1):

So as usual just after I post something, I think of an answer.

I have now

```
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{nodot}{}{}{}{}{}{}{ }{} %%the space is important here

\theoremstyle{nodot}

\newtheorem*{ex*}{Example}
```

which assigns no number at all, and replaces the full stop with a space so that I don't get a dot between the word Example and the number I then insert manually, via:

```
\begin{ex*}\ref{EarlierLabel} (continued). 
...
\end{ex*}
```

Ah well.

Comment: This might be an answer to your problem but is a fragment only. No one else but you will be able to get a real working code of it.